# Strange response from server

Tags: php, forms

When I copy and past formatted text from MS Word to My WySwung editor. On submitting the form server gives the following response.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /administrator/uploadprocess.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request
```

I have deleted the htcaccess file. but still having the same issue. plz help

Comment: Does it process fine if you type something in the editor manually

Comment: yes it works if simple text or formatted in the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are copying data from ms word and hten the encoded characters go to mysql and have problem so yes I think you should use mysql_real_escape_string function. While the other two issues you mentioned still seems odd. Please provide a bit more detail that do these issues come when you don't paste from word?

Comment: Yes, when formatted in the editor, it does not raise any error

Comment: it seems that it is somee sort of encoding error and don't expect that html editor should understand word formating. these are two different things.